# Translate text in ioncube encoded files using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, translate, encryption, ioncube

I am having a Ioncube php script i would like to translate entierly.

I have worked hard to perform the first part : translating the template files.  But, there is still lots of text stuck in the Ioncube encoded php files.

I heard someday it was possible, using jQuery to modify the output on the website

Does someone can explain to me how i can translate the text theses ioncube encrypted files output using jQuery or... ...please suggest any other way to do this.  i need this to be transparent for the visitor of the website in question.

Please note i do not want to decode the encrypted files.  I only want to change the text that appear on the page with something else.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would imaging the only way to do this with jQuery would be to do DOM manipulation after page loads.

For example if the Ioncube text is in a div with id "footer"

```
$(function() {
    $('#footer').load('http://somedomain.tld/translated/footer.php');
});
```

See the http://api.jquery.com/load/ documentation for more info

Comment: Hi,  This don't seems to work.  Also : some text do not have any id / class.   Something else i can try?

Comment: Without actually seeing the code you are dealing with its hard to suggest anything else.  My answer was an example of what 'could' work.  Can you post an example of the output you can't change via PHP and need to change with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code :

< iframe name="framename" height="500" scrolling="auto" src="about:blank" style="width:80%;border:1px solid #fff;">

this output a google authenticator page.

I need to modify the output of what's inside the iframe.

possible?